# How to align TextView in two lines between images in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, constraints, android-constraintlayout

I'm doing some design in constraintlayout that is give me a pain. I have an image at the left, two text in a vertical orientation that is align at the end of this image and I have other constraints at right with an image and text.

If I type a long text in the two text that i have in a vertical orientation the text cover the constraint that I have at right of my view. That I want to do is if this text is long can't cover this constraint, have to expand to other line.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_slider"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_error" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_title_animation_native_cart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/app_primary_medium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_slider"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_slider"
                tools:text="Title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_subtitle_animation_native_cart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textColor="@color/app_grey_medium"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txt_title_animation_native_cart"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_title_animation_native_cart"
                tools:text="Subtitle asfda sdfowei oiwue rpoweiru  oiwue twoeiu t oiweu t" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraint_undo_button"
                android:layout_width="31dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_undo"
                    android:layout_width="14dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_loop"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:src="@drawable/icon_loop"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Ree"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_primary_medium"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_undo" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why Don't you use a linear layout for that vertical text view. Also, You can do this in constraint layout as Hascher answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_subtitle_animation_native_cart"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textColor="@color/app_grey_medium"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txt_title_animation_native_cart"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_title_animation_native_cart"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/constraint_undo_button"
                tools:text="Subtitle asfda sdfowei oiwue rpoweiru  oiwue twoeiu t oiweu t" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use only one parent view and read about Guideline view, Constraints Chains and Barriers.  So a possible solution could be the next:
[image]

And the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <!-- In the parent constraint group add your custom background -->

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_80_percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_slider"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title_animation_native_cart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_80_percent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_slider"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image_slider"
        tools:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_subtitle_animation_native_cart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image_slider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/txt_title_animation_native_cart"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/txt_title_animation_native_cart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_title_animation_native_cart"
        tools:text="Subtitle asfda sdfowei oiwue rpoweiru  oiwue twoeiu t oiweu t adfadf adflkjadfkj adlkjadflk" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_undo"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text_undo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_80_percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_undo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/image_undo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image_undo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image_undo"
        tools:text="Ree" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need two nested constraint layouts, one is enough.
Then just set the text with endToStartoOf image_undo and set the width to 0dp instead of wrap_content